# Can I stake other assets than XTZ?

Tags: baking, proof-of-stake, staking

Is it possible to use other assets than tez (XTZ) in the staking or baking process? I was wondering if tokens on the Tezos blockchain could also be used.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, only tez (XTZ) can affect baker's rolls (staking balance) when delegated.

Comment: Got it. Thanks. What about plans? Is it something that would/could be supported?

Comment: Using something other than Tezos, on the Tezos blockchain, for staking/baking would make it no longer Tezos.

Comment: @ThorkilVærge I don't think it could be supported, because it may harm the whole Tezos' economy. For example, if tokens affected baker's "power", I could issue unlimited amount of my own tokens (for free!), delegate it to myself and become the largest baker.

Comment: I agree, it would diminish the role of Tez. That being said, only **approved** tokens, without minting options, could be allowed to pariticipate in the baking, but that would of course open up a whole can of worms with respect to centralization and governance. Probably not a good idea.